# How to install python modules in a local directory? --user and exporting pythonpath isn't working

Tags: python, linux, module, pythonpath

I don't know very much about python but would like to install some python modules in a local directory on a server on which I don't have sudo access.

I start by going into my desired directory (not root) and create the directory tree needed to store my custom modules

```
cd /root/example/sub-example
mkdir -p local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I then export this local path to `PYTHONPATH`

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/root/example/sub-example/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I then make a new sub-directory to store the python package while extracting

```
mkdir example-python-directory
cd example-python-directory
wget http://example-python-package
tar -xvf example-python-package.tar.gz
cd example-python-package
```

Last, I run the setup.py script with the `--user` flag to try to get it to install in my specified `/local` directory

```
python setup.py install --user
```

The problem is, nothing is installed in my `/root/example/sub-example/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory, and instead I find that I now have a new directory at root: `/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Is there a way to prevent this? I feel like my lack of Python knowledge is causing me to make some silly error that is probably obvious to others. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why did you expect that `--user` would do something different?

Comment: Is there some flag I should be using to specify my intended /local path?

Answer (score 5):

create a folder called "lib"

## For Python 3

```
pip3 install <your_python_module_name> -t lib/
```

## For Python 2

```
pip install <your_python_module_name> -t lib/
```

Comment: to the current directory:

pip install <your_python_module_name> -t . (dot at the end instead of the path)

Answer (score 1):

`CFLAGS=-I$(brew --prefix)/include LDFLAGS=-L$(brew --prefix)/lib pip install <package>`

I found that on servers where you haven't root access to, you can usually install the python module into your .brew/lib using this.

Answer (score 0):

[*virtualenv*](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) is what I would recommend for this case (and pretty much any other case). I use it for pretty much everything I do in *Python*.

It allows you to essentially create a sandbox containing a *Python* environment that is bootstrapped from a *Python* install on your machine, and to install any modules you want into it.

It should not, in general, require the use of *sudo*, since you're not touching the system install. You can generally `pip install` a module right into the *virtualenv*, and then you run your scripts out of that *virtualenv*. You would basically just need a location you can read/write/execute from, say a directory you create in your user's *home* directory.

You can keep track of what's installed by doing a `pip freeze > requirements` and checking that into an *SCM*, and then a new *virtualenv* can be recreated using that file, ready to run your scripts.

The link I provided above has more details about how to use *virtualenv*.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

You can still use `pip install` outside of *virtualenv*, and I would recommend that. However, that can only operate on various *Python* installs that may be on the box (invoke `pip` from the *bin* directory of the install you want to use).

However, that won't work for installation into arbitrary directories. For that, you could try to unzip the *egg* file (they are supposed to be zip files) into the directory you want, and then make sure that directory is on the `PYTHONPATH`. Some *egg* files are available for direct download off of [*PyPI*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), although some are source only.

I think is approach is much more complex and prone to problems than *virtualenv* would be, though.

Comment: I appreciate the insight and will look into virtualenv, but can you also tell me if you know of a way to simply install in my desired /local as well?